# Insert Link Button In String Builder

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I created a dynamic link button, which needs to be inserted in a `StringBuilder` to not ruin the design of my aspx page.

So here's a "part" of my code where I need to insert my LinkButton:

```
design.Append("<h3>");
NewAddToCart(); //This is where my linkbutton should be inserted 
design.Append("</h3></div>");
```

My NewAddToCart() is constructed on the following code:

```
private void NewAddToCart()
{
    LinkButton lbtnAddtoCart = new LinkButton();
    lbtnAddtoCart.ID = "lbtnCart" + i;
    lbtnAddtoCart.CommandArgument = i.ToString();
    lbtnAddtoCart.CssClass = "glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart pull-right";
    lbtnAddtoCart.Click+=lbtnAddtoCart_Click;

    using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
    {
        using (HtmlTextWriter html = new HtmlTextWriter(sw))
        {
            lbtnAddtoCart.RenderControl(html);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to return the rendered string something like `return sw.ToString()`. Then, replace `NewAddToCart();` to `design.Append(NewAddToCart());`

Comment: oh i just did it. thanks.. but my problem is that it doesn't trigger the click event. but i'll find some solution. thanks for the help sir @MoshFeu

Comment: did you find the solution? i tried to do this tooo